# How to download a file from a folder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, directory

I want to download a file in documentsDirectory in folder "tracks". But if I use this code (file download in documentsDirectory). All work fine

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Chapter.mp3"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:false];

NSString *stringURL = @"link";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

And if I use this code(file download in documentsDirectory in folder "tracks") file is not downloaded

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tracks/Chapter.mp3"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:false];

NSString *stringURL = @"link";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

How to download a file in documentsDirectory in folder "tracks"?

Comment: Try adding; if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: filePath isDirectory:&isDir])
    if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath: filePath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL])
        NSLog(@"Error: Create folder failed %@", directory);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tracks folder probably doesn't exist yet. You need something like:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *tracksPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tracks];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:tracksPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:tracksPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}
```

Comment: If I use this code in `viewDidLoad` folder with objects(chapter) will not replace an empty folder?

Comment: This code calls `fileExistsAtPath` to see if it needs to create the folder.  If it's already there, it does nothing.